# How to run a consuming process before sending data with ajax and jquery on the background with the spinner running?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to send data to server using ajax, but the problem is that I have a consuming process before sending the data.

The process takes about 5 seconds and the spinner has to run in the process.

So in my code the spinner doesnt show until the ajax call starts (probably because the process is blocking everything)

If I move the call "consumingprocess" into "beforesend",  then it doesnt work and I am not sure why.

So the question is how to show the spinner, while everything is beeing called (the consumingprocess and the ajax call)

Thanks

This is my code:

```
$("#btnAccept").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
          //start spinner, works fine but only shows after consumingprocess has finished
          $.mobile.loading( 'show' );

             console.log("btnAccept");

     var data =  consmuingprocess();
       console.log(data);
     // data is fine

                                 $.ajax({
                                           type : "POST",
                                           url : url,
                                           dataType : "xml",
                                           contentType : "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
                                           data : data,
                                           requestHeaders : {
                                            Origin : '*'
                                            },
                                           crossDomain : true,
                                           beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                                           console.log("beforeSend");
                                           },
                                           error : errorAJAX,
                                           success : parseXml
                                           });

            });

        });
```

Comment: If your process is that heavy then showing the spinner will do no good as it probably won't spin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is

- call your loading window
- delay so the loading window has a chance to display
- run the rest of your code.

You would do this using an interval:

```
$("#btnAccept").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
    var intervalId;

    function delayedStuff = function() {

        // make sure we only run this once
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);

        var data =  consmuingprocess();

        $.ajax({
            // set up your ajax request and handlers
        });
    };        

    $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
    // wait 1/2 second, then run delayedStuff
    intervalId = window.setInterval(delayedStuff, 500);
});
```

But this technique comes with an important caveat: while your very expensive `consumingProcess` function is running, all animations and javascript still comes to a halt.  On Chrome, even animated gifs stop running.  All we've done here is just given your page changes a chance to display.

There are a couple of possible solutions available:

- Take a closer look at your `consumingprocess()` function and see if it can be optimized.  There is probably a faster way to do whatever it is you're doing that's taking so long.
- Use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).  The downside is compatibility: IE and most older browsers don't support it.  I haven't done multi-threaded programming with JavaScript at all, so I don't know how effective this is.

Comment: Thanks,  as you said the animation stops when the process is running but at least is showing the message.